# jQuery, append only part of an element without losing its content (possibly with clone?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone, target

I'll start by saying I'm not overly confident with my web development abilities and its entirely possible I'm going about this all wrong, but anyway here goes.

I would like to be able to .append on a small part of an element (target of where to open the link) as I don't know what its content will be.

For the purposes of demonstration, I use this below to append all the results I get back from a search request.

```js
$("#results").append("<div><a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title) + "'>" + item.title + "</a> : " + item.snippet + "</div>");
```

What I would like to be able to do is to further append these results when the user clicks on one of the links, the Target for this would be a new tab within the webpage which isn't present at the time of the first .append (also achieved with jQuery)

I was thinking I could try to use .clone to get the content of the div, remove the html (as to end up with just the link) and then use this as input into another .append

Am I going about this in the wrong way? I worry that attempting to change the HTML for the link when the user clicks on it will cause problems.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need to clone the div element. You might be able to achieve what you want by attaching a click handler for the link:

```
$('#results').append('div>[ your code from above ]</div>')
    .find('a')
    .bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var a = $(this);
        var url = a.attr('href'); // here is the url

        // call some other function    
});
```

My apologies if I have missed what you are trying to do here. But hope this helps you.